# Trying to return a Bool Value from a class in C++

Tags: c++, class, boolean

I'm very new to the world of coding and C++. I'm tasked with taking numbers from a .txt doc with different lines of values. I need to do error checks on each line to make sure the file is in the correct format. I was hoping to make a class that I can reuse in order to do these checks. i,e:

1. get data from first line
2. check to see if data matches criteria (this case it has to be 1 or 0 and I will have to apply different operations later on based on this value)
3. Trigger a true / false if statment in the main file based on results.

**Main.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <functional>
    #include "ErrorSwitch.h"
using namespace std;

//Set pointer of 'file' to beginning line of 'num'
fstream& GotoLine(fstream& file, unsigned int num) {
    file.seekg(ios::beg);
    //Loop through file
    for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i) {
        file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return file;
}
int main() {
    fstream file("file1.txt");
    //Check Line 1
    GotoLine(file, 1);
    //Get Input from First Line & Convert to int
    string line1;
    file >> line1;
    int inpu = stoi(line1);
    //Error Check
    ErrorSwitch checkOne;
    checkOne.input = inpu;
    checkOne.errorCheck();
    if (checkOne == true) { //I can't seem to get this to work as a boolean check
        //Do code here
    }
    else if (checkOne == false) {
        //Do code here
    }
    
}
```

**ErrorSwitch.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class ErrorSwitch
{
public:
    int input;

    bool errorCheck() {
        switch (input) {
        case 0:
            return true;
            break;
        case 1:
            return true;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Can someone please have a look at this and help me understand how I can get a return value from this class function.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bool value is returned from the function `errorCheck`, not the class itself.

You can store the return value to a variable like this:

```
    bool checkRes = checkOne.errorCheck();
    if (checkRes == true) {
        //Do code here
    }
    else if (checkRes == false) {
        //Do code here
    }
```

or simply do:

```
    if (checkOne.errorCheck()) {
        //Do code here
    }
    else { // if bool is not true, it is false
        //Do code here
    }
```

Alternatively, you can add an operator to convert the class to `bool` like this

```
    operator bool() {
        return errorCheck();
    }
```

to the class `ErrorSwitch` to have this code work:

```
    if (checkOne == true) { //I can't seem to get this to work as a boolean check
        //Do code here
    }
    else if (checkOne == false) {
        //Do code here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
checkOne.errorCheck();
if (checkOne == true) {
    //Do code here
}
else if (checkOne == false) {
    //Do code here
}
```

To this:

```
if (checkOne.errorCheck()) {
    //Do code here
}
else {
    //Do code here
}
```